# Magento 2.2.7. Best way -according to the Magento guidelines- to apply some custom javascript to specific products

Tags: magento2.2, javascript, product-list

At `app/design/frontend/Custom/Theme/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/list.phtml` I'm trying to apply a javascript for certain products (not all of them) as follows:

```
<?php foreach ($_productCollection as $_product): ?>
    <?php if ($_product->getData('custom_attribute')): ?>
        //some javascript that apply for the products that contain the attribute
    <?php endif; ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

What would be the best approach to achieve this in a way that the Magento good practices are guaranteed. Thanks for your input and collaborations

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not specific, but I can try to answer:

1. Turn on flat tables for products.
2. Add new attribute (just like in your question) and make sure that "used in product listing" is set to Yes. Type should be Boolean. (That's crucial - your newly created attribute values will be stored inside flat table).
3. Add changes in list.phtml (for example like in your question).

There won't be any additional db queries to run (if you setup attribute just like I suggest in 2.) to get your values and it will only add one little column to Magento collection query with boolean values.

There are more places to add your code (.phtml files), but you can easily find them inside layout .xml file.

Comment: Hii; i was thinking about executing some javascript inside the if statement; i know it is not a good practice to place the javascript inside the if statement, so i was then wondering what the best approach would be. The attribute has been defined already, so getData checks if the products have already the attribute